# Excel: conditionally add icon based on min/max column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In excel, I'm trying to put an icon on input cell if input is greater/lower than max/min. Min/Max values are defined in a column for each row, see example.

```
     A     B     C
1    Input Min   Max
2    10    0     20
3    -5    -2    3     <--- should have icon
```

I can't find a tutorial on how to use the GUI for conditional formatting on this subject. Can it be done at all?

**edit**: to clarify, I'm trying to use this GUI interface:

[image]

**Edit**: to better clarify, issue is how to apply this to any number of rows, automatically (with the least amount of human interaction needed).

Comment: You need a different rule for each row, but you can use VBA to automate creating them.

Comment: Hate to hear this. Are you able to give an example on VBA? I'm a total newbie on VBA, plus it strikes me that I cannot find a tutorial online for this specific problem. It looks like a common scenario to me

Comment: Use the macro recorder and record adding an icon to one row... that will give you a head start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by BigBen, I've sketched the solution using the Macro Recorder, then edited the macro by hand. It is not a smooth process, but works somehow for me.

Known limitation: you have to apply this row by row. By setting up a quick key combination, the operation gets easier, yet not recommended for a huge notebook.

Any improvements on this script are welcome!

```
Sub Encoder_input_validation()
'
' Encoder_input_validation Macro
' Adds input validation to inputs in Encoders based on Min/Max
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+V
'
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
        .ReverseOrder = False
        .ShowIconOnly = False
        .IconSet = ActiveWorkbook.IconSets(xl3Symbols)
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).IconCriteria(1).Icon = xlIconRedCrossSymbol
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).IconCriteria(2)
        .Type = xlConditionValueFormula
        .Value = "='<your worksheet name>'!$<"Min" column Letter>$" & Selection.Row
        .Operator = 7
        .Icon = xlIconNoCellIcon
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).IconCriteria(3)
        .Type = xlConditionValueFormula
        .Value = "='<your worksheet name>'!$<"Max" column Letter>$" & Selection.Row
        .Operator = 5
        .Icon = xlIconRedCrossSymbol
    End With
End Sub
```

Will print a red cross if input is greater than max or smaller than min. Apply on the "input" cell to validate, this way user is notified whenever a out-of-boundary input is prompted in the computing sheet.

Comment: You can use a loop instead of using `Selection.Row`... but yeah this is pretty close to what the final code would look like.